# is it possible write a text in Cucumber report with custom css?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

this it a sample:

```
import cucumber.api.Scenario;

public class MyStepdefs {
    private Scenario scenario;

    @Before
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    @Given("^I print a text in Cucumber report$")
    public void print() {
        scenario.write("This goes into the report(s)\n");
    }
}
```

by defaut, the css is the same (`embedded-text`)

```
.cucumber-report .step .embedded-text {
  background: #dddddd;
}
```

I want write more one style text in my report (info type A, info type B, ...).

Comment: What do you mean by "write a text in cucumber report?" Are you trying to get syntax highlighting to work for embedded code in the HTML report?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, I want `scenario.write("text A");` with background yellow, `scenario.write("text B");` with background orange, ... (NOT always #dddddd)

Comment: Have you tried `scenario.write("<span style='color:yellow'>text B</span>")` to see if inline HTML and styles propagate through to the HTML report?

Comment: Can you add info about how you are running the tests and generating the HTML report?

Comment: `scenario.write("<span style='color:yellow'>text B</span>")` is good idea but in my formatter.js, I replace `currentStep.append('<pre class="embedded-text">' + text + '</pre>');` by `currentStep.append('<pre class="embedded-text">' + String(text).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '</pre>');` if I want print XML text.